# PHP Laravel 5.2 - Folder not found code exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm making a simple upload system, for some reason it keeps giving me the error I programmed if the folder doesn't exist, even if it exists. I've tried to put the URL of everything that is, the directory of the folder is below.

```
    public function anexar()
    {

        $diretorio = "imagens/";

        if (!is_dir($diretorio)) {
            echo "Folder $diretorio not found";
        } else {
            $arquivo = isset($_FILES['arquivo']) ? $_FILES['arquivo'] : FALSE;
            for ($controle = 0; $controle < count($arquivo['name']); $controle++) {

                $destino = $diretorio . "/" . $arquivo['name'][$controle];
                if (move_uploaded_file($arquivo['tmp_name'][$controle], $destino)) {
                    echo "Upload realizado com sucesso<br>";
                } else {
                    echo "Erro ao realizar upload";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Directory]

[image: error]

Comment: What you get if you dump `getcwd()`?

Comment: What happens if you set your directory to be relative to the controller: `$diretorio = "./imagens/";`

Comment: @Damon same error :(

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ "/home/owwassi3/public_html/secad" its folder of project in ftp

Comment: So does it show you the path to the base directory of your project? If so, try  `$diretorio = getcwd()."/app/controllers/imagens";`.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ same error :( "Folder /home/owwassi3/public_html/secad/app/controllers/imagens not found" and "Folder /home/owwassi3/public_html/secad/app/controllers/imagens/ not found"

Comment: If you don't have a special reason to store images in the controllers directory, I suggest you use the storage one, where you can use the Storage facade of laravel, and everything will be easier for you https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Solved, thanks. I made a small adjustment to your solution and it worked: D

Comment: Great. Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has several [path helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers) you can use

```
$diretorio = app_path('controllers/imagens');
```

although you should really be storing user uploads in `storage_path('sub/path')` and symlinking them to the `public` folder.